# loop over fields and all classes and lists contained in our object (angularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop

I want to copy a field to another fields using angular, so I use this loop:

```
        for (var k in $scope.customer) {
        $scope.customer[k].fr = $scope.customer[k].en;
        $scope.customer[k].es = $scope.customer[k].en;
    }
```

But the problem is that the loop works only with ordinary fields(int, string ...) which means: the loop don't fit into the lists and classes in my object.
is there a way to loop over the fields and all classes and lists contained in my object?

**Update**

For example I want to copy the field "en"  to "fr" and "es" fields.

My model : `CompanyName(en: String, fr: Option[String], es: Option[String])`

To do this I should write:

```
$scope.customer.Company.CompanyName.fr = $scope.customer.Company.CompanyName.en;
$scope.customer.Company.CompanyName.fr = $scope.customer.Company.CompanyName.es;
```

There is any way to apply this using a loop? without specifying each field?

Comment: The structure of the original code and the update are different, though. What's the real structure?

Comment: It's the same thing, you can find here my classes: http://pastebin.com/nU0Ljf4u what I want is to copy all the "en" field to "fr" and "es" fields for each class or lists contained in my object.

Comment: Well, see my answer. Does it work?

Comment: Ok I tested my answer with your edits and it worked with some fake test data, so it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with a deep copy function, which I implemented here (I tested it, it works) :

```
function deepCopyEn(src) {

  if (src.hasOwnProperty("en")) {
    src.fr = src.en;
    src.es = src.en;
  }
  else {
    if (src.constructor === Array) {
      for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
          deepCopyEn(src[i]);
      }
    }
    else {
      for (var prop in src) {
        if(src.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            deepCopyEn(src[prop]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usage :

```
deepCopyEn($scope.customer);
```

You can test it [here](https://repl.it/BwTg).

Comment: your function worked fine for the first class but when I tried with another class which content an array it didn't work can you help me please !! this is an example : http://pastebin.com/K7EjAnu1

Comment: yes and also if I add another simple field link "test"

Comment: I don't see how it *could* work, you don't have any `en` properties in the objects of your `contacts` array

Comment: yes, I solved it by adding a first test to check for scalar types. thank you again for your replay

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try foreach loop :

```
$scope.customer.forEach(function(cust){ 
// work with cust
});
```

It will get all property of cutomer object in cust.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. can you please check the update !!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `angular.copy()` to create a full deep copy of the English version:

```
for (var k in $scope.customer) {
    $scope.customer[k].fr = angular.copy($scope.customer[k].en);
    $scope.customer[k].es = angular.copy($scope.customer[k].en);
}
```

And later overwrite the language specific fields for the other languages. Her's a source on `angular.copy()`: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/angularjs-copy-vs-extend/